# How to draw lines between SWT TreeItems

Tags: java, swt

I need to write an editor with two Trees, where user can map nodes from one tree to another. The biggest challenge is to draw connection line between TreeItems.
Are there any samples that I can use?

There is the link for JDeveloper XSD Mapper tree view
https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/images/xsdMapper.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560452/eclipse-rcp-combining-table-rows-by-drag-and-drop-the-arrows).

[image]

There is also the Nebula [`TreeMapper`](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/treemapper/treemapper.php). Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I looked at TreeMapper the problem with  that ,the connection line its not up to actual node ... i need some how to connect line to the node..

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein What do you mean with "it's not up to actual node"?

Comment: if you look at the link I posted, you will see the connections between the nodes are almost touching the node. It's easier to see it than explain it. :)

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein I don't think it is possible to draw lines in the left hand part of the TreeViewer where the node expansion toggles are shown.

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein Found [another related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280706/java-treeviewer-swt-right-to-left). The OP is using two trees, one of the left-to-right and is drawing stuff between them. Maybe you can contact the OP and ask for the code.

Comment: @MariaFinkelstein *"One of them right-to-left" is what I meant.

Comment: @Baz nice, i think i got all i need, can't wait to get to the office and try it :)